# How can I know the number of support vectors of each fold in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, classification, svm

I'm using the `caret` package for cross validation. The classifier I choose is `svmLinear` from the `kernlab` package.

```
ctrl = trainControl(method="cv",number=5,savePredictions="none",classProbs=F);
costSeq = c(1e-3,1e-2,1e-1,1,1e1,1e2);
costPara = expand.grid(C=costSeq);
svm.model = train(Y~.,data=myData,method="svmLinear",tuneGrid=costPara,trControl=ctrl);
```

How can I know the number of support vectors of EACH model candidate respect to each cost parameter? The command `svm.model$finalModel` provides the number of SVs of the final model. I know the attribute `nSV` in `kernlab` tells the number of support vectors, but I don't know how to display this attribute. I tried `svm.model$nSV`, but the result is `NULL`.

Comment: just a side note - there is nearly no point in analysis of number of SV for linear kernel, as you can always compute the actual hyperplane equation which is of dimension of input space. SVs are a computational bottleneck/important analytical factor etc. only in kernel case.

Comment: Thanks for the note. It's not easy to obtain the number of SVs when there are slack variables. Moreover, as you pointed out, it would be even more non-trivial to analyze the number of SVs when the method is switched to the RBF kernel.

Comment: No, it is not what I am refering to. I am just saying that for linear model the concept of SV is a bit redundant. Obtaining SV is pretty straight forward - neither kenel nor slack variables make it problematic. Definition is clear - if the lagrange multiplier is non zero - it is a support vector, period.